# If $\Vert f(t,x)\Vert_{W^{1,\infty}((0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R})}\le C$, what conditions imply $f(t,x) \to g(x)$ uniformly as $t \to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f:[0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $$\Vert f(t,x)\Vert_{W^{1,\infty}((0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R})}\le C,$$ where $C$ is a constant. What conditions imply $$f(t,x) \to g(x)  \text{ uniformly as } t \to \infty,  $$
where $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is independent of $t$?

Comment: What kind of convergence do you have in mind? Your condition is equivalent to saying $f$ is bounded and Lipschitz on $(0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$. In particular $f_t(x):=f(t,x)$ are uniformly bounded and Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R}$ so by Arzela-Ascoli and a diagonal argument there is a subsequence $t_k$ and a function $g$ such that $f_{t_k}\to g$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. If the limit function $g$ was unique (i.e. the same along any subsequence) then you get a version of your result.

Comment: @Jose27 I'm thinking about global uniform convergence. But is the limit function obtained by Arzela-Ascoli independent of $t$?